# Replacing fragments in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, appcompatactivity

I have an Android app with a SlideMenu.

This is most of the MainActivity where I have the sideMenu:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle sideMenuToggle;
    private DrawerLayout sideMenuLayout;
    private SideMenuAdapter mAdapter;

    ...

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("title", options.get(posit).getString("visual_name"));
            if(posit == Constants.INDEX_USERNAME)
                goToView(ViewManager.EDITPROFILE, data);
            else if((posit >= Constants.INDEX_SECTION_1) && (posit <= Constants.INDEX_SECTION_5)) 
            {
                Bundle category = options.get(posit);
                data.putString("title", category.getString("visual_name"));
                data.putString("visual_name", category.getString("visual_name"));
                data.putString("name", category.getString("name"));
                data.putInt("photo", category.getInt("photo"));
                data.putInt("ico", category.getInt("cat_ico"));
                data.putBoolean("is_root", true);
                goToView(ViewManager.CATEGORYFRAGMENT, data);
            }
        }
    }

    public Fragment goToView(ViewInfo _viewInfo, Bundle bundle)
    {
        try 
        {
            if((this != null) && !this.isFinishing())
            {
                ViewManager myVMgr = viewMgr;
                return myVMgr.show(_viewInfo, bundle, false);
            }

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is most of the code of the ViewManager where I switch between sections (they are fragments):

```
public class ViewManager 
{

    private Activity context = null;

    ...

    public Fragment show(ViewInfo _newFragInfo, Bundle _data,  boolean back)
    {
        Fragment currentFragment = null;
        Fragment newFragment = null;

        final FragmentManager fm = context.getFragmentManager();
        ViewInfo _lastFragInfo = lastViewData != null ? lastViewData.getViewInfo() : null;

        // In this app we must support changing between same fragment class
        //if((_lastFragInfo != null) && _newFragInfo.getIdView().equalsIgnoreCase(_lastFragInfo.getIdView())) {
        //    return null;
        //}

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        if(_newFragInfo.getIsRoot())
        {
            Iterator<ViewData> iter = viewStack.iterator();
            ViewData viewData;
            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                viewData = iter.next();
                if(!viewData.getViewInfo().getIsRoot())
                {
                    currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(viewData.getViewInfo().getIdView());
                    if (currentFragment != null)
                    {
                        ft.remove(currentFragment);
                    }
                }
                iter.remove();
            }
        }

        // Hide current fragment
        if (_lastFragInfo != null)
        {
            currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(_lastFragInfo.getIdView());
            if (currentFragment != null)
            {
                if(!back)
                    ft.detach(currentFragment);
                else
                    ft.remove(currentFragment);
            }
        }

        // Show new fragment
        if (_newFragInfo != null)
        {
            if(_newFragInfo.getIsRoot() || back) // only tabs are reusable fragment
                newFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(_newFragInfo.getIdView());
            if (newFragment == null)
            {
                newFragment = Fragment.instantiate(context, _newFragInfo.getClaseView().getName());
                ft.add(R.id.frame_content, newFragment, _newFragInfo.getIdView());
            }
            else
            {
                ft.attach(newFragment);
            }

            if(_data == null)
                _data = new Bundle(1);

            if(!_data.containsKey("title"))
                _data.putString("title", context.getResources().getString(_newFragInfo.getTitle()));

            if(!_newFragInfo.getIsRoot() && !back)
            {
                viewStack.add(lastViewData);
            }

            ((BaseFragment)newFragment).setData(_data);
        }

        lastViewData = new ViewData(_newFragInfo, _data);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
        return newFragment;
    }
}
```

In the sideMenu, "Edit profile" option has its own Fragment and Section 1 to Section 5 use the same fragment but I load a different content.

This is working well so far and when the user opens the sidemenu and changes between sections they are loaded correctly.

But now I've uploaded my code to use target sdk 26 and it doesn't compile because ActionBarActivity is no longer available so I've made these changes:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

to this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

and inside ViewManager

```
private Activity context = null;
```

to this

```
private AppCompatActivity context = null;
```

This now compiles but when I change between sections the data of the new section is no loaded and I keep watching the content of the previous section.

Some examples:

1)

1.1) I select Section1 (I see the content of Section1)

1.2) I select Edit Profile (I see the content of Edit profile)

1.3) I select Section3 (I see the content of Section3)

2)

2.1) I select Section1 (I see the content of Section1)

2.2) I select Section3 (I don't see the content of Section3 but the content of Section1).

Checking this I've seen that the problem is because with AppCompatActivity, onCreate, onCreateView and onResume methods of my CategoryFragment are called in steps 1.1, 1.3 and 2.1 but not in step 2.2.

Am I missing something? Should I make a new change so the Fragments transactions are made correctly with AppCompatActivity?

-- EDIT --

The setData method of the Fragment is this:

```
public void setData(Bundle _newdata)
{
    data = _newdata;
}
```

I've thought to change it to this:

```
public void setData(Bundle _newdata)
{
    data = _newdata;
    // Some code to force the refresh/reloading of the Fragment
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is a tricky way to fix this, and by the way, I don't know how to force a fragment to reload itself.

Comment: My idea is to set flag for each `Fragment` then handling the current `Fragment` and Inflating the needed `Fragment`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you very well. Debugging my code I've seen that in both samples the line "Fragment.instantiate(...)" is called, so I assume it's inflating the fragment. But no oncreate or onresume methods are called in the second sample.